# running an sql query on an entire table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a listing of employees (in srat) and if their survey_results (in sr) are qualified or not qualified. kt is a list of all of the possible activities and has either qualified or unqualified.

```
SELECT  srat.employee_email,srat.taxyear, sr.item, kt.qualified, kt.unqualified 
FROM survey_results_activities_temp srat, survey_results sr, key_temp kt
WHERE sr.user_email=srat.employee_email AND sr.taxyear=srat.taxyear
AND sr.item_type='AC' AND sr.item=kt.activity
```

This runs fine and returns the 4 rows from the sr table with the qualified or unqualified appended onto it.  But I'd like it to run for all the employee_email's in srat. Now it only runs for the first one. What am I doing wrong? BTW, I am using mySQL.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, _and easier to convert to outer join if needed_!

Comment: Can you show us some data  because we can not see if you should get back more results than 4 with this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Based on your description, you want `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT srat.employee_email, srat.taxyear, sr.item, kt.qualified, kt.unqualified 
FROM survey_results_activities_temp srat LEFT JOIN
     survey_results sr
     ON sr.user_email = srat.employee_email AND
        sr.taxyear = srat.taxyear AND
        sr.item_type = 'AC' LEFT JOIN
     key_temp kt
     ON sr.item = kt.activity
```

Comment: OK. I modified the query into the new format:            $sql = "SELECT  srat.employee_email,srat.taxyear, sr.item, kt.qualified, kt.unqualified 
             FROM survey_results_activities_temp srat JOIN survey_results sr ON srat.employee_email=sr.user_email
                                                      JOIN key_temp kt ON kt.activity=sr.item
             WHERE sr.item_type='AC' ";  This comes up with the 4 entries

Comment: @band . . . That's nice.  That is not the query in this answer.  In particular, this has no `WHERE` clause.